# System information in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

This problem, it is necessary in the admin module to arrange a viewing system information such as CPU load, memory, etc.
Advise with the help of which one can achieve such a conclusion in Yii framework? Perhaps js library, Yii extensions?

Comment: Check out this PHP project https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo

Answer (score -1):

Check out [phpSysInfo](https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo)

Now you can get some points by accepting an answer ;)

Comment: You are mean. You clearly haven't worked out how SO works yet. People read answers before comments so I'm sure I'll have positive up ticks before you hit pubity!

Comment: some people get reputation answering questions, some people  copy-pasting answers from the same page, if they get the same reputation would you treat such situation as fair?

Comment: Yes, they are fair. Some people get reputation from fixing spelling mistakes and formatting code. Their contributions are just as valid. This is an unanswered question and appears in the unanswered list. I am trying to move it out of the Unanswered list and this is my contribution - which is just as valid as anyone else's.